# how I can pass html text to angularjs template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

how I can pass html text to angular js template.

for eample  for the below template I want to pass task.data as "this is task xyz  status of task"

now on web page I can see html tags . please help me to fix this.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="default.tooltip.tmpl.html">
    <div class="gantt-task-info" ng-style="css">
        <div class="gantt-task-info-content">
            {{ task.data }}</br>
       {{ task.link1 }}  </br>
            <small>
                {{ task.isMilestone === true && (task.from | date:'MMM d, HH:mm') || (task.from | date:'MMM d, HH:mm') + ' - ' + (task.to | date:'MMM d, HH:mm') }}
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem by using ng-bind-html directive

see below reference code

```
<div class="gantt-task-info-content">
        <p ng-bind-html="task.data"></p></br>
        <p ng-bind-html="task.link1"></p></br>
```

hope this will help

Comment: see I need to update code to take this working . the code which binds data to template is like below now

Comment: return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
            if (tAttrs.templateUrl === undefined) {
                return "default.tooltip.tmpl.html";
            } else {
                return tAttrs.templateUrl;
            }
        },
        replace: true,
        scope: { task: "=ngModel" },
        controller: ['$scope', '$element', function ($scope, $element) {
            var bodyElement = angular.element($document[0].body);
            var parentElement = $element.parent();
            $scope.visible = false;
            $scope.css = {};